# "Dynamic" constructor c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, constructor

Is it possible to create a form of "dynamic" constructor in c#? That would create itself based on the constructor input but actually create a subclass and not "really itself"? 
I have something like this in mind:

```
public NeuralNet(arg arg1, arg arg2....)
{
    NeuralNet specificNet;
    if(arg1==something){
        specificNet = new subClassFromNet(arg2...);
    }
    else if(arg1 == something){
        specificNet = new otherSubClassFromNet(arg2...);
    }
    ...

    this = specificNet;

}
```

or is it necessary to create a method like this

```
public static NeuralNet CreateNet(arg arg1, arg arg2....)
{
    NeuralNet specificNet;
    if(arg1==something){
        specificNet = new subClassFromNet(arg2...);
    }
    else if(arg1 == something){
        specificNet = new otherSubClassFromNet(arg2...);
    }
    ...

    return specificNet;

}
```

Setting all the properties in the constructor of the super class is not a viable method for me as the constructors for the subclasses are too big. At the moment i have the second method implemented but i think the first option would be more user friendly. Also i think it looks better. 
I know that i could create several constructors in the superclass but for some reasons i'm interested if this particular method would be possible. 
I'm very sorry if this question has already been asked but i didn't find an answer to it nor am i an experienced enough developer to find a suitable method by myself.

Comment: You're talking about [Factory Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern), I guess.

Comment: Take a look at the factory pattern.

Comment: Your question already has a working solution to your own problem; there's nothing left to answer.

Comment: Note that the fact that you're even inclined to do this is a pretty strong signal that you should be using composition here, not inheritance.  You should of course favor composition over inheritance in general, but given what you're trying to do it seems inheritance is a particularly poor fit for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do "dynamic" constructors. C# doesn't let you overload operator new like other languages. You must use the static builder method.

```
public static NeuralNet New(arg arg1, arg arg2....)
```

Another benefit of static builder methods is that they can be async (whereas the ctor must always be sync). 
    public static Task NewAsync(arg arg1, arg arg2....) // does network IO